# SQL 'FROM' not where expected

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

A follow on from a previous question

I'm working with an oracle 11g DB and need to manipulate a string column within it. The column contains multiple email addresses in this format:

jgoozooll@gmail.com;dzhookep@gmail.com;admzmoore@outlook.com

What I want to do is take out anything that does not have '@gmail.com' at the end (in this example admzmoore@outlook.com.com would be removed) however admzmoore@outlook.com may be the first email in the next row of the column so in this way there is no real fixed format, the only format being that each address is seperated by a semi-colon.

Is there anyway of implementing this through one command to run through every row in the column and remove anything thats not @gmail.com? I'm not really sure if this kind of processing is possible in SQL. Just looking for your thoughts!!

Getting the above 'FROM' error in the following code and I cant for my life figure out why. Someone will probably make me look stupid, but its a chance i have to take. There may also be other errors:) Heres my code:

```
 SELECT REMIT_TO.ID
 , LISTAGG(EMAIL, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY REMIT_TO.ID) REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR

 FROM (SELECT REMIT_TO.ID 
        , regexp_substr(REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR, '[^;]+', 1, RN) email

    FROM IQMS.REMIT_TO
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM RN
                   FROM(SELECT MAX (REGEXP_COUNT(REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR, '[^;]+')) ML
                          FROM IQMS.REMIT_TO
                        )
                       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ML
                  )
     )                             
 WHERE EMAIL LIKE '%@gmail.com%'
 GROUP BY REMIT_TO.ID
```

Anything stick out for anyone?

Thanks you guys.

Comment: PS. Thanks to Nicholas Krasnov for the help with the above code!!

Comment: I hope those are fake email addresses that you included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are missing a few aliases on your subqueries:

```
SELECT REMIT_TO.ID
 , LISTAGG(EMAIL, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY REMIT_TO.ID) REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR
FROM 
(
  SELECT REMIT_TO.ID 
        , regexp_substr(REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR, '[^;]+', 1, RN) email
  FROM IQMS.REMIT_TO REMIT_TO
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT ROWNUM RN
    FROM
    (
      SELECT MAX (REGEXP_COUNT(REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR, '[^;]+')) ML
      FROM IQMS.REMIT_TO
    ) x2 -- alias needed
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ML
  ) x1   -- alias needed  
) REMIT_TO   -- alias needed                         
WHERE EMAIL LIKE '%@gmail.com%'
GROUP BY REMIT_TO.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

My Oracle is a but rusty, but on first look you're missing a comma after the LISTAGG function.

```
SELECT REMIT_TO.ID
 , LISTAGG(EMAIL, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY REMIT_TO.ID)
 , REMIT_TO.EFT_EMAIL_ADDR...
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is driving me crazy. It seems to be the word 'GROUP' that is causing the error. I have the appropriate commas in elsewhere!!!